# Prove that $T$ is a subgraph of $G$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree with $k$ edges, and let $G$ be a graph where every vertex has degree at least $k$. Prove that $T$ is a subgraph of $G$.

Can someone give me tips/help on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You additionally have to assume that $G$ has at least one vertex. But then, I'd use induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Start with *any* vertex $t_1 \in T$ and map it to *any* vertex $g_1 \in G$ (assuming one exists, as [pointed out by celtschk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441978/prove-that-t-is-a-subgraph-of-g#comment947521_441978)).
- Pick *any* neighbour $t_2 \in T$ of $t_1$ and map it to *any* unused neighbour $g_2 \in G \setminus \{g_1\}$ of $g_1$,
- ... repeat until finished.
- You will always be able to pick an *unused* neighbour in $G$ because you have $k+1$ vertices to map and each vertex in $G$ has at least $k$ neighbours (i.e. that gives you $k+1$ vertices along with the currently mapped one).

I hope this helps ;-)